# Change InputText-Values with Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf

So I have a bunch of InputText-Boxes, which express some kind of customer data (customer-id, firstname, lastname, etc.)

Now i want to auto-fill (with the corresponding mysql data) all InputText-Boxes, when I enter a valid customer-id.

```
<h:inputText id = "customer_id" value="#{reservationHandler.customer.customer_id}"/>
```

I guess I'll have to use Ajax to pass the current customer-id to the managed bean, but how do i do this? And how do i fill the other InputText-Boxes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using JSF 1.x or JSF 2.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task can be done using the `<f:ajax>` tag that comes with JSF 2 and is good illustrated in [this tutorial](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/04/learning-jsf-2-ajax-in-jsf-using-fajax-tag/). The first example shows you how to accomplish the task at hand. Another advice would be to use `@ViewScoped` annotation for your managed bean as explained by BalusC blog post: [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Managed bean scopes](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes).

With all this info and the managed bean you're using, a demo could be:

Customer class

```
public class Customer {
    private int customer_id;
    private String name;
    //constructor, getters and setters...
}
```

ReservationHandler managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ReservationHandler {
    private Customer customer;
    //this EJB will retrieve the Customer data
    //if you don't have it like this, then use your own 
    //custom CustomerService class/implementation to retrieve the data from dabatase
    @EJB
    private CustomerService customerService;
    //constructor, getters and setters...
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        customer = new Customer();
    }
    public void showCustomerDataListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        Customer customerFromDB =
            customerService.getCustomer(customer.getCustomer_id());
        if (customerFromDB != null) {
            customer = customerFromDB;
        }
    }
}
```

Customer Facelets view (just the relevant code)

```html
<h:form>
    <h:outputText value="Customer ID:" />
    <h:inputText id="customer_id"
        value="#{reservationHandler.customer.customer_id}">
        <f:ajax event="blur"
            listener="#{reservationHandler.showCustomerDataListener}"
            render="customer_name" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:outputText value="Customer name:" />
    <h:inputText id="customer_name"
        value="#{reservationHandler.customer.name}" />
</h:form>
```

In case your `Customer` class posses more than 1 attribute, you have two options:

1. Set the ID of every input in the `render` attribute of the `<f:ajax>` component, but this is very naive.
2. Group all the components with an `UIContainer` and render this UIContainer. Example given assuming that the `Customer` class has an additional `private String address` attribute:

   ```html
   <h:form>
       <h:outputText value="Customer ID:" />
       <h:inputText id="customer_id"
           value="#{reservationHandler.customer.customer_id}">
           <f:ajax event="blur"
               listener="#{reservationHandler.showCustomerDataListener}"
               render="customerData" />
       </h:inputText>
       <h:panelGrid id="customerData" columns="2">
           <h:outputText value="Customer name:" />
           <h:inputText id="customer_name"
               value="#{reservationHandler.customer.name}" />
           <h:outputText value="Address:" />
           <h:inputText id="customer_address"
               value="#{reservationHandler.customer.address}" />
       </h:panelGrid>
   </h:form>
   ```

To know the supported events that cna be applied in `<f:ajax event="what_to_write_here">`, refer to [f:ajax JSF Core Tag Reference](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_ajax.html), event tag attribute description:

> The event that will invoke Ajax requests, for example "click", "change", "blur", "keypress", etc. **The event must be supported by the component(s) that have Ajax behavior enabled**. Note: **the event name is the same as the DOM event name without the "on" prefix**, so for the "onclick" event the correct event name is "click". The "action" event is supported for command components such as h:commandButton and h:commandLink, and the "valueChange" event is supported for input components such as h:inputText and h:selectOneMenu.